# How to ensure syslog captures maximum possible log before abrupt system power off

Tags: linux, syslog

I observe that `syslog` file (`/var/log/messages`) doesn't seem to capture the latest possible log before abrupt system shutdown. (My Linux system is running and then abruptly there is a power loss.)  How do I ensure that `syslog` captures the maximum possible logs before the abrupt shutdown?

Comment: You might not want to do that from a point of view of performance. Also, there is no way around it that a portion of logs will always be lost, that is why is called abrupt. What are you really trying to accomplish? I would advise asking the real question behind this "solution".

Answer (score 0):

Minimize or disable writeback cache and its timeout.

```
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio
dirty_ratio
dirty_expire_centisecs
dirty_writeback_centisecs
```

Comment: As I understand the , `write-back` cache setting is for the underlying Hard-drive, you either `enable` it or `disable` it. Where as the other options like `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio` provided are for the operations like flushing for  Data present `in-memory`. Could you please elaborate on the answer , perhaps also stating the optimal values to be set for these parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two ways a system goes down.

1. Graceful shutdown: In this case every process running in the system gets a chance to write some logs, flush the buffers onto the disk before going down.In this case in `/var/log/messages` you can see

   `kernel: Kernel logging (proc) stopped.`

   `rsyslogd: exiting on signal 15.`
2. Abrupt shutdown: Here the applications wont have a chance to write logs, `filesystem` will not have a chance to flush the data onto the disk.  But if this is the scenario you are facing , you might want to check the system hardware like `HDD , SSD and power supply [ for any unwanted fluctuations ]` to debug the issue effectively.

But as a resort to frequently persist the data from cache to the disk. You can periodically try running the `sync` command which flushes file system buffers. For more checkout `man sync`

Answer (score 0):

Note, if you are using rsyslog legacy format in your `/etc/rsyslog.conf` with a line like

```
*.=info;...  -/var/log/messages
```

you can remove the `-` prefix before the filename, and this will make syslog sync the file after every write. See [regular files](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/actions.html#regular-file).